# Determine the equation of the line passing by $(3,4)$ which minimizes the area of the triangle determined by its intersection with the coordinate axis

Tags: calculus, solution-verification, analytic-geometry

Below is a problem that I did. I do not have faith in my answer. Is  my answer right?

Problem:

Consider the equation of a line going through the point $(3,4)$ with a negative slop. It will form a triangle with the y-axis and the x-axis. Find the equation of the that goes through this point and minimizes the area of the triangle.

Answer:

We see a triangle formed by the line and the two axis. The general form of
the equation of a line is:
$$ y = mx +  b$$
In our case, we know that $m$ will be negative. Three points define a triangle. One of those points is $(0,0)$. Another point is $(b,0)$. Now we need to find the point where the line crosses the x-axis. We have:
\begin{align*}
mx + b &= 0 \\
mx &= -b \\
x &= -\dfrac{b}{m}
\end{align*}
Hence the third point is $\left( -\dfrac{b}{m}, 0 \right) $. Hence the length of the base is $ \dfrac{b}{x} $. The height of the triangle is $b$. Let $A$
denote the area of the triangle.
\begin{align*}
A &= \left( \dfrac{1}{2} \right) \left( -\dfrac{b}{m} \right) b \\
A &= - \dfrac{b^2}{m} \\
4 &= 3m + b \\
b &= 4 - 3m \\
A &= - \dfrac{(4-3m)^2}{m} = - \dfrac{(3m-4)^2}{m} \\
A &= \dfrac{ -9m^2 + 24m - 16}{m} \\
A &= -9m - 24 - 16m^{-1} \\
\end{align*}
Now we differentiate $A$ to find a minimal value for $m$.
\begin{align*}
A' &= -9 + 16m^{-2} \\
-9 + 16m^{-2} &= 0 \\
\dfrac{16}{m^2} &= 9 \\
\dfrac{4}{m} &= -3 \\
m &= -\dfrac{3}{4} \\
b &= 4 - 3\left( -\dfrac{3}{4} \right) = 4 + \dfrac{9}{4} \\
b &= \dfrac{25}{4}
\end{align*}
Hence the answer is:
$$ y= -\left( \dfrac{3}{4} \right) x + \dfrac{25}{4} $$

Here is a corrected / updated solution. However, the answer did not change. Is my revised solution correct?

Now, I see a triangle formed by the line and the two axis. The general form of
the equation of a line is:
$$ y = mx +  b$$
In our case, we know that $m$ will be negative. Three points define a triangle. One of those points is $(0,0)$. Another point is $(b,0)$. Now we need to find the point where the line crosses the x-axis. We have:
\begin{align*}
mx + b &= 0 \\
mx &= -b \\
x &= -\dfrac{b}{m}
\end{align*}
Hence the third point is $\left( -\dfrac{b}{m}, 0 \right) $. Hence the length of the base is $ \dfrac{b}{x} $. The height of the triangle is $b$. Let $A$
denote the area of the triangle.
\begin{align*}
A &= \left( \dfrac{1}{2} \right) \left( -\dfrac{b}{m} \right) b \\
A &= - \dfrac{b^2}{2m} \\
4 &= 3m + b \\
b &= 4 - 3m \\
A &= - \dfrac{(4-3m)^2}{2m} = - \dfrac{(3m-4)^2}{2m} \\
A &= \dfrac{ -9m^2 + 24m - 16}{2m} \\
A &= \dfrac{-9m - 24 - 16m^{-1}}{2} \\
\end{align*}
Now we differentiate $A$ to find a minimal value for $m$.
\begin{align*}
A' &= \dfrac{-9 + 16m^{-2}}{2} \\
\dfrac{-9 + 16m^{-2}}{2} &= 0 \\
-9 + 16m^{-2} &= 0 \\
\dfrac{16}{m^2} &= 9 \\
\dfrac{4}{m} &= -3 \\
m &= -\dfrac{3}{4} \\
b &= 4 - 3\left( -\dfrac{3}{4} \right) = 4 + \dfrac{9}{4} \\
b &= \dfrac{25}{4}
\end{align*}
Hence the answer is:
$$ y= -\left( \dfrac{3}{4} \right) x + \dfrac{25}{4} $$

Here is an updated solution. Is is it now correct?

Now, I see a triangle formed by the line and the two axis. The general form of
the equation of a line is:
$$ y = mx +  b$$
In our case, we know that $m$ will be negative. Three points define a triangle. One of those points is $(0,0)$. Another point is $(b,0)$. Now we need to find the point where the line crosses the x-axis. We have:
\begin{align*}
mx + b &= 0 \\
mx &= -b \\
x &= -\dfrac{b}{m}
\end{align*}
Hence the third point is $\left( -\dfrac{b}{m}, 0 \right) $. Hence the length of the base is $ \dfrac{b}{x} $. The height of the triangle is $b$. Let $A$
denote the area of the triangle.
\begin{align*}
A &= \left( \dfrac{1}{2} \right) \left( -\dfrac{b}{m} \right) b \\
A &= - \dfrac{b^2}{2m} \\
4 &= 3m + b \\
b &= 4 - 3m \\
A &= - \dfrac{(4-3m)^2}{2m} = - \dfrac{(3m-4)^2}{2m} \\
A &= \dfrac{ -9m^2 + 24m - 16}{2m} \\
A &= \dfrac{-9m - 24 - 16m^{-1}}{2} \\
\end{align*}
Now we differentiate $A$ to find a minimal value for $m$.
\begin{align*}
A' &= \dfrac{-9 + 16m^{-2}}{2} \\
\dfrac{-9 + 16m^{-2}}{2} &= 0 \\
-9 + 16m^{-2} &= 0 \\
\dfrac{16}{m^{-2}} &= 9 \\
16 = 9m^2 \\
-4 &= 3m \\
m &= \dfrac{-4}{3} \\
b &= 4 - 3 \left( -\dfrac{4}{3} \right)  = 4 + 4 \\
b &= 8 \\
\end{align*}
Hence the answer is:
$$ y= -\left( \dfrac{4}{3} \right) x + 8 $$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two (small) mistakes:

**(1)** You dropped the factor of $\tfrac12$ in your area formula, so you're actually minimizing the area of the rectangle with this diagonal. *This shouldn't affect your final answer though, as the minimum will occur at the same slope!*

**(2)** When solving for $m$, you flipped the fraction. The critical point is actually at $m = -\tfrac43$. This affects the final equation of the line, of course. Full solution is hidden below.

> The line that minimizes the area of the triangle is $$y = -\tfrac43 x + 8.$$ If you write the equation in standard form, it looks like $$4x + 3y = 24$$ in which you can easily recognize the coordinates $(a, b) = (3, 4)$ and the area $2ab = 24$. Hence, the solution to the general problem with point $(a, b)$ is the line $$bx + ay = 2ab$$ with area $A = 2ab$.

Comment: I have updated my solution. Is it now correct?

Answer (score 2):

Given a rectangle $ARPQ$ with sides $\overline{AR} = a$ and $\overline{QA} = b$, we claim that, among the right-angled triangles circumscribed to $ARPQ$ (see figure below), the one with the smaller area is $ABC$ with $\overline{AB} = 2a$ and $\overline{AC} = 2b$.

[image]

Consider another right-angled triangle $AB_1C_1$, and suppose first $AB_1 < AB$, as in the figure above, where $BH$ and $CK$ are perpendicular to $B_1C_1$. Denoting with $[\cdots]$ the area of the triangle in parenthesis, we have
\begin{eqnarray}
[AB_1C_1] &=& [ABC] + [PCK] + [CKC_1] - ([PBH]-[BHB_1])=\\
&=& [ABC] + [CKC_1] + [BHB_1] > [ABC],
\end{eqnarray}
where we used the fact that $PCK \cong PBH$ (ASA criterion).

I leave you as an exercise to work out in a similar manner the case where $AB_1 > AB$.

---

So the triangle with minimum area has area $[ABC] = 2[ARPQ] = 2ab$. In your case $A$ is the origin of the axes, and $P$ is the point having coordinates $(3,4)$. So the mimimum area is $24$ and the slope of the straight line is $-\frac{b}{a} = -\frac43$.

Answer (score 1):

If the line makes an angle of $\theta$ with the negative direction of the $x$ axis, then its unit normal vector is $(\sin \theta, \cos \theta)$, and therefore its equation is

$ \sin \theta (x - 3) + \cos \theta (y - 4) = 0$

The $x$ intercept is $ \dfrac{ 3 \sin \theta + 4 \cos \theta }{ \sin \theta } $

The $y$ intercept is $ \dfrac{ 3 \sin \theta + 4 \cos \theta } {\cos \theta } $

So the area of the triangle is

$ A = \dfrac{1}{2} \dfrac{ (3 \sin \theta + 4 \cos \theta)^2 }{ \sin \theta \cos \theta } $

And this simplifies to

$ A = \dfrac{ (12.5 + 3.5 \cos(2 \theta) + 12 \sin(2 \theta)) }{ \sin(2 \theta )} $

Differentiating, and equating the numerator to zero, gives us,

$  - 7 \sin^2 (2 \theta) + 24 \cos(2 \theta) \sin(2 \theta) - 25 \cos(2 \theta) - 7 \cos^2(2 \theta) - 24 \cos(2\theta) \sin(2\theta) = 0$

and this simplifies to,

$ -7  - 25 \cos(2 \theta) = 0 $

Hence,

$ \cos(2 \theta) = -\dfrac{7}{25} $

$ 2 \cos^2(\theta) - 1 = \dfrac{7}{25} $

$ \cos^2 (\theta) = \dfrac{9}{25} $

From which $\cos \theta = \dfrac{3}{5} , \sin \theta  = \dfrac{4}{5} $

Therefore, the equation of the line is

$ \dfrac{4}{5} (x - 3) + \dfrac{3}{5} (y - 4) = 0 $

which simplifies to

$ 4 (x - 3) + 3 (y - 4) = 0 $

i.e.

$ 4 x + 3 y - 24 = 0 $

So that

$ y = - \dfrac{4}{3} x + 8 $

Answer (score 1):

Let the side on $y$-axis be $4+b$ and on $x$-axis be $3+a$. By similarity $\frac b3=\frac 4a$ hence $ab=12$.

The area of the triangle is $$A=\frac12 (4+b)(3+a)=12+2a+\frac{18}a=24+2\frac{(a-3)^2}{a}\geq24$$
Equality occurs when $a=3$ and hence $b=4$. The line is passing through $(0,8)$ and $(6,0)$. So it is $y=-\frac43 x+8$.

Answer (score 0):

Notice that $y = mx + b = 0$ implies that $x = -b/m$. Notice as well that $x = 0$ implies that $y = b$.

Since the point $(3,4)$ belongs to such line, we conclude that $4 = 3m + b$.

Consequently, the area that we are interested in is given by:
\begin{align*}
A & = \frac{1}{2}\left(-\frac{b}{m}\right)b = -\frac{b^{2}}{2m} = -\frac{(4 - 3m)^{2}}{2m} = -\frac{9m^{2} - 24m + 16}{2m}
\end{align*}

which is (almost) the function that you have obtained: you forgot to divide by $2$.

Hopefully this helps!

Comment: @Aitla Correia You are right I am missing a $2$ in the denominator. However, I claim that does not change the answer.

Comment: @Bob Indeed. Since $(af(x))' = af'(x) = 0$ implies that $f'(x) = 0$, the constant does not affect the value of the critical point.